# jQuery Mobile Listview Long Item

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Im using jQuery Mobile listview with data-inset="true"`

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="e">
    <li><h3> ... long string ... </h3></li>
</ul>
```

If the item was too long, the string was truncated. Is there other way or best approach to display the whole long string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BxfhV/

```
ul li .ui-li-heading {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```